# Explain how this oneliner list of lists merger works?

Tags: python, list, flatten

```
[j for i in listOflists for j in i]
```

this code returns a merged list but I can't trace how it works, can anyone explain

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a nested `for` loop. The equivalent is

```
results = []
for i in listOflists:
    for j in i:
        results.append(j)
```